# Copying field values when creating a child Workitem in TFS?

Tags: tfs, workitem

We have a TFS team project using the Agile process template.
We have added a string field to the User Story and Task work item types.
This field is a dropdown bound to a global list.

When you create a new linked workitem from an existing workitem (using the NEW button on the LINKS tab for example), the Assigned To, Area and Iteration values are copied to the new linked item.

We would like to also copy the value for the string field that we've added, so that it does not have to be set manually.

Any ideas if this is possible using TFS customization?

Comment: If you are doing this because you have to create a lot of new WI's at once and it would be nice to have that value in all then I would use the excel interface where you can make the bulk edit.

Comment: This is more about value inheritance: tasks should inherit the property value from the parent, so that the user doesn't have to manually set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible... but not with "out of the box" work item features.  You'd need to write some custom code with the SDK (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssdk) to get this behavior.

Comment: Yes - that's what I've concluded as well: http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/ has the beginnings of what's needed.